# How do I train the VGG network when multiple classes are present in one training example?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn, one-hot-encoding, multiclass-classification

I recently switched to TFlearn to get some calculations on my network accuracy for classifying images and creating state of the art results. I am using [this](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/vgg_network.py) exact file from TFlearn, except for the dataset. I wanted to reproduce the accuracy for the VOC2007 dataset, downloaded all images and groundtruth and wrote a function that creates a 4D Tensor containing all images and a 2D Tensor containing all class indices. Their shapes are [?, 224, 224, 3] and [?, 20] respectively. Now i noticed, that the class indices are not one-hot labels, but several classes can be present in one image. Since TFlearn allows more than one class to be present, the network performs really badly (accuracy ~30%, and yes, i changed the number of output classes). I wonder, how to get around this problem. Should i only allow one class per image? But then, if there are two classes in an image and i classify it correctly according to the second class, this would be a correct detection that i would missclassify as an error. Is there any option that i am missing? I don't see a "one-hot" option or anything similar (like in the oxflowers dataset).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the loss function you are using for your multi-label problem?

Comment: I am using the standard `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` as the loss function.

Comment: Are you using the 'sigmoid' activation for the last layer? since its a multi-label problem

Comment: Yes, I did, but I also used softmax in order to get a distributed output. Either way i ended up with bad results.

Comment: you can't use softmax for  a `multilabel` problem: Multiple outputs needs to output 1.